# Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

And I have no idea where is it coming from. The stacktrace is not clear about it either. The query that throws this error:

```
Database::executeQuery('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_inventory ENGINE=MEMORY '
                . 'SELECT id, email_hash, mailing_list_id, ttl, price, last_click, last_view, extra_data '
                . 'FROM inventory i INNER JOIN mailing_list ml on i.mailing_list_id = ml.id '
                . 'WHERE i.active = 0 AND i.deleted = 1 AND i.completely_deleted = 1 AND i.resting_to < NOW() AND i.next_sync_at < NOW() AND ml.active = 0 '
                . 'LIMIT 10;');
```

So I have two tables - inventory, and mailing_list. Inventory has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email_hash` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `mailing_list_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_send_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `resting_to` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `next_sync_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ttl` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `completely_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_view` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_view_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

And the mailing_list:

```
CREATE TABLE `mailing_list` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
  `ttl` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '604800',
  `resting_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email_from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_return_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: The query doesn't know if the id field is comming from the table mailing_list or inventory. You should use i.id or ml.id

Comment: @Unex You should post that as an answer so khernik can validate it :) It is all about prefixing queried fields with the right table name or alias

Comment: Yeah i know, but it felt too easy to win points from it :D

Comment: I cant change queries :D If anything, I only can change the database structure.

Comment: you can't change queries ? what the hell are you working on ? You could change the name of the id field that you don't want. But srsly it's a very extremly bad solution !

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are accessing 2 tables: `inventory` in your FROM clause, `mailing_list` in your INNER JOIN clause.
Both of these tables have a column named `id`, so your db doesn't know which column you are referring to.

To fix this, specify the table in your select, by replacing `id` with `i.id` or `ml.id`

Comment: I can't change queries, only table structure.

Comment: The `mailing_list.id` column is referenced in the INNER JOIN clause, so you can't change that column name. You could change the `inventory.id` to something like `inventory._id`, but then you would have to change the SELECT clause